# Strange float bug

Tags: html, css

Anyone know why these `<li>` tags that contain the thumbnail pictures are not stacking up appropriately?

This is blowing my mind away.

http://hqinternetsolutions.com/Websites/NuPhase/index.php?id=4

All the floats, are right, and there's enough width.

**Update**

I'm using Firefox 6.0

Comment: If you would post some code, the community at large could probably be of more assitance.

Comment: which browser are you looking at it with? According to Firebug, there are a number of jQuery errors. Perhaps they are affecting things?

Comment: Can you provide the browser/version/os where the error is occurring? I went to the page and the navigation looked fine in Firefox, but we need some more help

Comment: @leopic, i'm not seeing any jquery errors in FF.

Comment: @leopic, sorry about that.  NoScript was preventing jQuery from loading because it's at a different url. That's why I saw errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing strange here - the behaviour is expected.

Most of your `li`s have a computed height of `58px`. However, some of them are slightly different, for example `64px` or `57px`. The reason for this is that some of the images are a different height.

The best fix is to simply make all the images the same height.